# Is CakePHP encryption not working well?

Tags: php, cakephp, md5

I have an old database with a PHP pass + salt md5 encryption, which i'm trying to use with CakePHP but cake encryption result doesn't match mine :

```
$pass = 'francis';
$data['raw_pass'] = $pass; 
$data['cake_hash_pass'] = Security::hash($pass, 'md5', $use_salt);
$data['php_md5_pass'] = md5($pass . ($use_salt ? '123' : ''));
var_dump($data);
```

with `$use_salt = false;` here is the result :

```
array
    'raw_pass' => string 'francis'
    'cake_hash_pass' => string 'd0ab7fe6c314f4fe5b6c18a0157c96b4'
    'php_md5_pass' => string 'd0ab7fe6c314f4fe5b6c18a0157c96b4'
```

It matches, no problem. But when I add the salt `$use_salt = true;`

```
array
    'raw_pass' => string 'francis' (length=7)
    'cake_hash_pass' => string '74055e005d086abb69c1f82e8bf1f061' (length=32)
    'php_md5_pass' => string '8d709b4b6461aef614529a83d883c64b' (length=32)
```

Results are not the same... I'm kind of stuck here, on CakePHP documentation I can read :

"boolean $salt optional false

If true, automatically appends the application's salt value to $string (Security.salt)"

Is using "." in `$pass . '123'` not appending ?

Also, in my core.php file :

```
/**
 * A random string used in security hashing methods.
 */
    Configure::write('Security.salt', '123');
```

Comment: you mean hashing, not encryption

Answer (score 0):

> Is using "." in $pass . '123' not appending ?

You can test that right now and let us know:

```
$temp = ($pass . ($use_salt ? '123' : ''));
echo $temp;
```

Comment: Following this link: http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/security#line-86, I figured out that CakePHP append salt before the pass. I was doing the opposite ;)